# How to add orange diamond tool to custom shapes?

Tags: mxgraph, draw.io, diagrams.net

I've noticed that some shapes in draw.io/diagrams.net come with a little orange diamond that allows internal shape modification like say rim thickness

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to add something like this to my own custom shapes?

Comment: Only programmatically in JavaScript.

Comment: would much appreciate for pointing out any sort of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no explicit documentation available on this, but you can just use the source code as a reference. The "orange diamond" is called "handle", you need to look for "custom handles", `createHandle` in the source code. You can take a "basic triangle" as an example.

This one provides a good starting point:
https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/blob/d60ab053c39cf9b9925dd329306536c00c364c84/src/main/webapp/shapes/mxBasic.js#L598